# Reorder multiple div within a div by relying on child input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to rearrange the div (including its child elements) within a div through jQuery by just referencing to the input ids.

My HTML below:

```
<div id="fields">
    <div class="field fieldContainer">
        <label for="field0" id="_lblFirstName"> First Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <input id="field0" name="firstName" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="field fieldContainer">
        <label for="field1" id="lblLastName"> Last Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <input id="field1" name="lastName" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="field fieldContainer">
        <label for="field2" id="lblEmailAddress"> Email Address <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
        <input id="field2" name="emailAddress" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my output to be Last Name, First Name, Email Address. I have done this but I needed to put IDs on each div. Will there be anyway to rearrange if the div even without an ID?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use .parent()? That should get the parent of the input element you select via the Id. eg. $('#field2').parent()

Comment: You can refer to a certain element's parent `<div>` by using `.parent("div")` or `.closest("div")` if nested multiple tiers apart.

Answer (score 0):

Using **.siblings** you can have all the elements in the same hierarchy.
So, you can get all the elements, clear the main div, and append the elements in order you want. For ex:

```
//Get all siblings
var divs = $('.fieldContainer').siblings();

//Clear the main div
$(".fields").empty();

//Append the elements in whichever order required
$(".fields").append(divs.eq(2).html());
$(".fields").append(divs.eq(1).html());
$(".fields").append(divs.eq(0).html());
```